# can CAS be stateless?

Tags: java, spring, single-sign-on, cas

CAS 3 is designed to be stateful,as it use spring webflow and store the tgt in memory(or database);
Is it possible to make CAS stateless ?
can I  achive that by removing the webflow and storing tgt in cookie ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, the cas-server is stateful by requiring a session for the login-process (default session-timeout: 5 minutes) and by having an application-wide ticket-registry, which stores all valid tickets (ticket-granting tickets and service-tickets).

Since the authentication-logic is built (and tested) on top of spring webflow I would not recommend to exchange this part for an own implementation.

Why do you want to make the cas-server stateless?

Answer (score 1):

The TGT is already being stored in a cookie.

See the "/login" URI:
http://www.jasig.org/cas/protocol

Comment: but TGT is also stored in TicketRegistry, which is stateful.